# ImageMagick Fails to identify .eps files (no decode delegate)

Tags: macos, imagemagick

ImageMagick is failing to identify (or convert) any .eps files, with a **no decode delegate** error. Below is the full error. Note that running ps2pdf wrapper for Ghostscript does successfully convert the sample EPS file to PDF, but... I guess since ImageMagick can't identify the format, that probably doesn't matter.

`identify: no decode delegate for this image format "/my_sample.eps" @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.`

System info:

```
ImageMagick 6.8.7-0 2013-10-28 Q16
Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
```

identify -list format | grep EPS returns:

```
 EPS  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript
EPS2* PS2       -w-   Level II Encapsulated PostScript
EPS3* PS3       -w+   Level III Encapsulated PostScript
EPSF  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript
EPSI  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript Interchange format
```

Comment: Also the Mac OS X "file" command reports the file type information as: DOS EPS Binary File Postscript starts at byte 32 length 221789 TIFF starts at byte 221821 length 184329.

Answer (score 1):

What do

```
convert -list configure | grep -i delegate
convert -list delegate
```

return? The following file(s) contain(s) the definitions for all your local delegates' setup:

```
ls -l $(convert -list delegate | grep Path: | sed 's#Path: ##')
```

So what does

```
grep sDEVICE $(convert -list delegate | grep Path: | sed 's#Path: ##')
```

return?

It may be the case that your EPS file is tainted with some "foreign" data such as PJL commands which are prefixed to the official `%!PS...`-header lines. This may make the auto-identification of the file impossible. Did you check this?